# How to add color to an exclamation mark?

Tags: html, css

I have an exclamation mark in my markup. It is displaying fine, but I want it to be colored red. Instead, however, it's showing up gray, as seen here:

[image]

My code:

```js
html += 
  '<td class="font-size-md">' +
    '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="padding-left: 2.5rem;">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="xxx_' + obj.xid + '" name="xxx' + obj.xid + '" ' + attributes + '>' +
      '<label for="xxx' + obj.xid + '" class="custom-control-label">' +
        '<span background-color:#113797>&#33;</span>' +
      '</label>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</td>';
```

The relevant portion of the code is here:

```js
<span background-color:#113797>&#33;</span>
```

Why isn't this setting the color to red?

Comment: A color or background color...please clarify?

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to red exclamation-mark

Comment: You may wish to have a look at the StackOverflow recommendation on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may feel this is not worth the effort, but in fact it is. If you follow the guidelines on that help page, you will get more answers, anwers that fit your needs better, and less downvotes. Use Google to translate the text to your native tongue if you are unsure that you understand everything or ask a friend to work through the text with you.

Comment: @RahulPatil: If you want the exclamation mark itself to be red, then you'll want to use `color` instead of `background-color`. Also, the JavaScript (I assume) may be distracting users from the core question, which is a pretty basic CSS issue. I've updated your post to move the image inline and format the code to multiple lines so it's easier to read. I've also made a few adjustments to punctuation and grammar, which may help people better understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a CSS property. In html, these properties are accessible through the `style` attribute of elements (among other paths). So your markup should read:

```
<span style="background-color:#113797;">&#33;</span>
```

You are setting, well, the background color for the box in which the exclamation mark glyph is rendered. If you wish to set the color of the exclamation mark, use the CSS `color` property instead.

Another quirk: The color you use is not red but a tint of blue. Check out the following inline code

```html
<span style="background-color: red;">&#33;</span>
<span style="color: red;">&#33;</span>

<span style="background-color: #113797;">!</span>
<span style="color: #113797;">!</span>
```

Comment: I m trying this stuck last 1 hour ```<span style="color: red;">&#33;</span>``` thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will make your "!" red. I added a `style="color:red"` to your `<span>` If you want the background to change, use `style="background-color:red"` instead. (You can use the color code instead of red as well. I used it here to see it easily)

```html
<td class="font-size-md">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="padding-left: 2.5rem;"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="xxx_' + obj.xid + '" name="xxx' + obj.xid + '" ' + attributes + '><label for="xxx' + obj.xid + '" class="custom-control-label"><span style = "color:red">&#33;</span></label></div>
</td>
```